# Where is the implementation of IEnumerable of Collection<T>

Tags: c#, .net, implementation

Suppose I have a `Collection<string>` and I'm using `GetEnumerator()` that returns `IEnumerator<string>`, where can I find the implementation of `IEnumerator` for this collection?

On MS [site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132409(v=vs.110).aspx) they just say:

> Returns an enumerator that iterates through the Collection.

But where is the class that implements `IEnumerator`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking into the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/collection.cs,281923b8611114ec) we can see that `GetEnumerator` returns the GetEnumerator of its' `items` field which concrete type is `List<T>` (inside the ctor)

That `GetEnumerator` returns an instance of `List<T>.Enumerator` an internal nested class whose source is available [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,d3661cf752ff3f44)

Comment: "which concrete type is `List<T>` (inside the ctor)" -- That depends on which constructor gets used.

Comment: @hvd true but in the other case the answer would be "it depends" not the most informative answer